# Add new values ​to an array if preg_match found match recursively with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, preg-match

how to add a new value to a multidimensional array keeping the key if preg_match found a match with the files in my directory ?

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $txt1 = $_FILES['filetxt']['tmp_name'];
    $txt2 = $_FILES['filetxt']['name'];

    $g = glob('./upload/img/*.*');

    foreach ($txt2 as $var) {

        $rap = explode(' ', $var);
        
        $zc = count($rap);

        for ($i=0; $i < $zc; $i++) { 

            $str = $rap[$i];
            $ext = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, "."));
            $pattern = "/$ext/i";
            
            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
            $array = array_map('array_filter', $matches);
            $array = array_filter($array);            
            
            }
            
        }
        var_dump($array);

    }


}
```

Here's result of $array (pattern for preg_match):

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "dropshipping"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "standards"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "boutique"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "vitrine"
}
```

I would like to apply preg_match on each value of the txt2 array and recursively insert the corresponding values ​​if the condition is true.

here's result of txt2 array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Texte dropshipping.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "Texte site standards.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "Texte sur boutique.txt"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "Texte sur les site vitrine.txt"
}
```

Comment: Aside: Use `foreach ($rap as $str)` instead of the `for` loop.

Comment: Ignoring the desired `preg_match`, are you sure the current code produces the values you're showing ? it doesn't seem right to me (without trying). Also you're pulling glob `$g` but never using it ?

Comment: You're splitting the names in `$txt2` into words, and calling `preg_match_all()` on each word. That's why you're only getting the last word before the extension in the results, instead of the whole filename.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do with preg_match_all. You're extracting the extension from `$str`, turning that into a regexp, and then matching it against the same `$str`.

Comment: The only way this will find multiple matches is if you have a filename like `txt_blah.txt`, where the extension is also part of the filename.

Comment: yea quite a few oddities in there.

Comment: You're reassigning `$array` each time through the loop, not adding to it.